# Simple Sending Email in Code Igniter (Modal, PHP, AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, email

I'm having a trouble of sending a simple email at my project I'm using CodeIgniter.

My codeigniter is Setup like this

application

assets

system

my sending email is on my assets/public/inquiry/Inquiry.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contactFrmSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && 
!empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

// Submitted form data
$name   = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

/*
 * Send email to admin
 */
$to     = 'paul.aliassistance@gmail.com';
$subject= 'Contact Request Submitted';

$htmlContent = '
<h4>Contact request has submitted at CodexWorld, details are given below.
</h4>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
        <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Message:</th><td>'.$message.'</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

// Set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Sales@euroits.com.au' . "\r\n";

// Send email
if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
    $status = 'ok';
}else{
    $status = 'err';
}

// Output status
echo $status;die;
}
?>
```

Now on my view which is at my application/views/templates/_parts/public_master_footer.php

> by the way I'm in a CMS that is why my path is like that

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm">Ask a question</button>
</div> 

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Form</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <!--ASK A QUESTION BACKEND-->
<script>
    function submitContactForm(){
        var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var name = $('#inputName').val();
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
        if(name.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your name.');
            $('#inputName').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
            alert('Please enter valid email.');
            $('#inputEmail').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(message.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your message.');
            $('#inputMessage').focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'https://www.euroits.com.au/assets/public/inquiry/inquiry',
                data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'ok'){
                        $('#inputName').val('');
                        $('#inputEmail').val('');
                        $('#inputMessage').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- END -->
```

Help me anyone please i tried it normally it works and it doesn't have an error it just throw my `else{statusMsg}` hays.

Comment: Why using php mail() function, try codeigniter's mail function()
Have you tested page with development mode on and see if there are any errors displaying?

Comment: I'm experimenting sir

Comment: Have you tested page with development mode on and see if there are any errors displaying?

Comment: how to test it sir??

Comment: in index.php of project folder search for ENVIORNMENT
and check if set as  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

Comment: it is set like this ```define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');```

Comment: CI has a [email user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) on how to use CI's email library. Maybe give this a try.

Comment: if your project is not in localhost, comment those lines and set environment as development

Comment: @BlessonChristy i can't comment it out sir because my project won't load its not on the localhost

Comment: @kerbholz i have already a phpmailer on it and its working perfectly fine . i just need to work out this normal email sending because i need it for some purpose

Comment: So first debugging step would be to check if you are getting `status = err`, or no `status`?  First case means your `mail` is failing; 2nd case means your POSTed data is somehow invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called **mailer.php** at application/controllers

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mailer extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('email@email.com', 'Name');
        $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
        $this->email->cc('another@example.com');
        $this->email->bcc('and@another.com');

        $this->email->subject('subject');
        $this->email->message('message');

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

}
```

Copy the above code and try with codeigniter built-in **email class**